# Object assign with inheritance not working in typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

The code was working when i was using it inside Angular project, then I decided to move to React and the code is working incorrectly.

```
class A {
  constructor(...parts: Partial<A>[]) {
    Object.assign(this, ...parts);
  }
}

class B extends A {
  id: string;
  constructor(...parts: Partial<B>[]) {
    super(...parts);

  }
}

const a = new B({ id: '123' });
console.log(a);
```

The output of console log is `B {id: undefined}` and i expect it to be `B {id: '123'}`

Here is tsconfig:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": false,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "strict": false
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

Here is the versions:

```
+ @types/jest@24.0.9
+ react-scripts@2.1.5
+ @types/react-dom@16.8.2
+ react@16.8.3
+ @types/react@16.8.6
+ typescript@3.3.3333
+ react-dom@16.8.3
+ @types/node@11.10.4
+ create-react-app@2.1.5
```

Minimum steps to reproduce:

- create-react-app test --typescript
- add code to App.tsx
- run and look into console

UPDATED:

I ended up using the following solution:

```
class B extends A {
  id: string = this.id;
```

Comment: No, it's working, https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-kd5v9f

Comment: @estus As I said it worked in angular project, the problem is that when i moved this into react project it stopped working. I think that the problem is with tsconfig but i dont't know exactly

Comment: I see no problem with the config and I'm unaware of any conditions under which this code would be compiled to something that would cause `{id: undefined}`. Whatever the problem is, the question doesn't show it. Consider providing https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve that can replicate it.

Comment: @estus Added steps to reproduce tryed on 3 different computers everywhere the same issue

Comment: It's correct. There issue does indeed exist when the code is run in create react app generated typescript codebase. The question is why..

Comment: Try to remove `id: string;` from class `B`.

Comment: Well magicly it works, but breaks intellisence... So i don't think that it is a solution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a [known problem](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/9105). It doesn't exist in TypeScript. The cause is that create-react-app TypeScript support uses TypeScript for type checking and Babel for transpilation.

This TS code

```
class B extends A {
  id: string;
  ...
}
```

is transformed to this ES.Next code:

```
class B extends A {
  id;
  ...
}
```

According to [class field proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields), unassigned `id` field is transformed to `this.id = undefined`.

In order to use the behaviour that is compliant to TypeScript, the setup needs to be changed to use `@babel/plugin-transform-typescript` to transpile to ES5 or use TypeScript instead of Babel, e.g. deprecated `react-scripts-ts`.

Answer (score 2):

Two possible workarounds:

1. Move Object.assign to child class
2. Create factory which will be returning instances of classes:

```
    export interface Ctor<T> {
        new(...parts: Partial<T>[]): T;
    }

    export class Factory {
        public static Get<T extends object>(ctor: Ctor<T>, ...props: Partial<T>[]): T {
            const res = new ctor();
            Object.assign(res, ...props);
            return res;
        }
    }
```